# Google Tag Manager how does it know pageview has occured?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-tag-manager, pageviews

I am trying to determine when gtm knows that a pageview has occurred

for instance if i have configure a pageview to be recorded at domready what is the flag of gtm that turns true when dom is ready and records that a pageview has occurred

I have read all the documentation from google and they do not provide this information.

Answer (score 1):

A pageview in GTM occurs when the GTM code is executed for the first time. When exactly that is depends on where in the page your GTM script is located.

That the DOM is ready is indicated by the [DOMContent​Loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event. This is not the same as a page view (pageview means GTM code has been downloaded and executed, DomReady/DOMContentLoaded means that the DOM tree is rendered, but external assets like images, stylesheets and JS files might not have been loaded yet).

The [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event means that both the DOM is ready and that every requested asset is fully downloaded. That might take some time (e.g. if you embed a marketing pixel and the server that hosts that pixel responds slowly then this will defer your load event, as the pixel cannot be downloaded in a timely fashion).

GTM maps these browser events to events in it's datalayer (gtm.js, gtm.dom and gtm.load respectively).